# Github shows unrelevant commits in pull request history

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I am using the "standard" flow well described on [this image](http://steveko.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/git-arrows31.png) with Github, namely:

- I have forked [SpringFramework](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework) project.
- I have cloned the [forked SpringFramework](https://github.com/dmak/spring-framework/) to my PC.
- When I want to add new feature I pull from [`origin`](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework).
- Then I create a branch, commit changes, push to my [`upstream`](https://github.com/dmak/spring-framework/) and create pull request.

I would like also to have certain files in tree be modified according to my needs (e.g. build rules). I want these changes to be present in `upstream` HEAD and propagated to newly created branches.

As a result, github shows shows the history of all merges I've done before I created a branch (see [pull#334](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/pull/334)). When clicking on [Files Changed](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/pull/334/files) tab one can see that it reports "2 changed files with 141 additions and 23 deletions", however the shown diff contains maximum 50 changes. I conclude that these numbers accumulate also changes from other commits in the history shown.

What I want to achieve:

- The history of changes in pull request show only relevant changes.
- The statistics is telling the truth (e.g. "2 changed files with 23 additions and 18 deletions").

What should I change in my flow and/or in my repository to fulfil the needs? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is probably to just rebase your changes off of the branch on origin that you're submitting the pull request to (probably master).

```
git rebase my-feature-branch --onto origin/master <current branch base>
```

Where `my-feature-branch` is the branch containing the feature you want to submit the pull request for, and `<current branch base>` is the commit immediately preceding the first commit you want in the pull request.

In the future, you can avoid these sort of messy commits by basing your feature branches off of commits which are already in origin, and only making commits on that branch that you want in the pull request.

For example, to create a new branch off of `origin/master`:

```
git fetch origin # Make sure origin/master is up to date
git checkout origin/master
git checkout -b "new_branch"
# Now do work on this branch.
# Don't make commits here that you don't want in the pull request
```

Comment: Thanks for advise. Could you be more verbose (in terms of `git` commands) what should I do to produce more "clean" pulls? Let's say, I have committed some changes into master, and switched to new branch `git checkout -b FIXING`. Then I do fixes and `git commit`. What comes next? `git rebase FIXING --onto origin/master master`?

Comment: @dma_k Assuming you wanted the `FIXING` branch in a separate pull request that would work. It would be better though if you avoided the need to rebase entirely by basing your `FIXING` branch off of `origin/master` in the first place. I've updated my answer with more details on that.

Comment: Thanks for improved answer. What you shown is how to switch to new branch. That is clear. At what moment to I need to commit, rebase & create new pull request? At what moment should I perform fast forward ? What should I do to add more changes to the `FIXING` branch (other words: continue fixing)? What should I do if I want to squash all changes in `FIXING` branch at the end? Thanks.

Comment: @dma_k Those sound like separate questions to me. (I'm guessing there are some fundamental aspects of git that you don't quite understand. Perhaps you should read [this](http://git-scm.com/book).) The point is, if you want to keep your pull requests clean you have to put the commits you want in the pull request on a separate branch and avoid making commits to that branch that you don't want in the pull request.